# Comparing two huge files in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Requirement is to compare two huge Unix files and writing the difference in third file based on a unique key (first field) after searching few options got the below command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' hosts.csv masterlist.csv>results.csv
```

Though this gives the differences, if for a field one file contains NULL (as a word) and other empty/space for null values how to ignore this in the command and compare other fields?

Also would like to make a generic script or utility with such options, don't need the code but just a suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Is `diff` not an option?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], otherwise this is too abstract to know what you are looking for.

Comment: @commuSoft: tried with sdiff -W... But need to ignore Null as well.. So was checking if we have a better method

Comment: It sounds like you have very specific requirements in terms of what are considered matches.  Try processing the files to change all NULLs into spaces and then comparing them.

Comment: @Neil Masson: tried that option with "sed '/NULL//g' filename"... As this runs through whole file and then the matching operation... Would there be any less intense command?

Comment: Please give example input (something like compare `key field1 NULL field3` with `key field1     field3` that seems to be no difference) and how to show the results. Does it matter when NULL is in first or second file?

Comment: How huge are your 'huge' files: megabytes, gigabytes, terabytes, bigger?  Reading all of one file into memory will be a problem if you're dealing with terabytes; it may be manageable if you're dealing with small numbers of gigabytes on a machine with more main memory than you have file.  If they're only megabytes in size, there isn't a big problem (they're simply not that huge as far as most machines are concerned). Can you determine which file is the larger of the two?  You want the smaller in memory and you can scan the larger a line at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this fix in your `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if ($0 !~ /NULL|  *|^$/){a[$0]}next}!($0 in a)' hosts.csv masterlist.csv>results.csv
```

As @fedorqui suggest in comments, here's another alternative:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if ($0 !~ /NULL/ && NF){a[$0]}next}!($0 in a)' hosts.csv masterlist.csv>results.csv
```

Comment: You can probably check `NF` to get rid of empty lines or those with just spaces.

Comment: @klashxx: yes, your command helped to some extent however due to bad data not able to completely compare

Answer (score 0):

try to compare them using binary. if you compress the file into a binary (serialization), you can then compare them quite rapidly. if there is a difference you can then go through the file and compare them using similar methods to git... check their source code. hope this helps